# Why is PHP varible still undefined?

Tags: php

I am working with three PHP files.  Two serve as web pages and the other in an external server side script.  The server side script is included in both web pages files and what I want to do is have some buttons on the first page and depending on which one is clicked, populate the second page with data and then redirect to it.

With the code below, the idea was to pick up the button click, figure out which button was clicked, and then call the function to run the proper query and set the needed variables.  I don't understand why the variable is not getting set.

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

First page's button (index.php):

```
<input type="submit" id='details' name='details' value='Submit'/>
```

Second page where variable is undefined when page is loaded:

```
<h4><?php echo $selected_button; ?></h4>
```

External script:

```
function detailBuilder(){

    $selected_button = "Option One";
    //header('Location: details.php'); if this is here, the page still redirects but the variable doe not get set
    //More will happen here once it works

}

if(isset($_POST['details'])){

    detailBuilder();
    header('Location: details.php');

}
```

Comment: This is what you read next: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php - first link in the tutorial...

Comment: you know when a page changes (header location) all scripts terminate and a new process begins, right? You'd need to pass that as a get var, cookie, or some other temp storage. location: details.php?selected_button=option-one... or some such

Comment: That code doesn't make sense so its not clear what you intend to do.

Comment: Your second page should contain `$selected_button = $_POST['whatever_your_element_is_named_as'];` ***if it is named***  while having a POST method. Show more code.

Comment: I believe Kai Qing's comment makes most sense so far. It's because you redirect user to different page. So your request "ends". And when it arrives to details.php, it's completely different story and you lose track of your previous variables.

Comment: I do not know if you have properly included the files on each page using  the `include` function. Though, a variable declared within a function(between the brackets) cannot be reached outside that function. We say the variable is _inside_ the function _scope_. The function also does not return anything.

Comment: I tried the same thing with a global variable and still had the same issue but that does make sense.

Comment: I'd really like to see what else is on the second page.

Comment: So reading @KaiQing 's comment, it sounds like I should store the selected choice in a cookie or the session, call the header function, retrieve the cookie, then call the needed function based on the cookie value that supplies the data to the second page?

Comment: define "global variable" - even global variables are used only on the page load. persistent variables, like session or cookie vars can stay across page loads, but you have to set and initialize them properly.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't really say "based on my comment" because I am not totally sure what you are trying to achieve here. By the looks of things you're using a form element. Why not just post directly to the details.php page and process the post vars there?

Comment: Are you saying to do something like this @KaiQing?        `<form action="details.php" method="post">
 
 <input type="submit" id='details' name='details' value='Submit'/>
</form>`

Comment: For starters yes. If your form is always going to toss the user to details.php you might as well post to that script.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The second page is just a bunch of data related to the category selected from the first page.  It is displayed in what is mostly tables and stacked bar graphs using JQPlot.  Each category will have a different data set so that is where I am going with that.

Comment: *"while having a POST method"* - which is what I said almost an hour ago.  *"Are you saying to do something like this `<form action="details.php" method="post"> <input type="submit" id='details' name='details' value='Submit'/> </form>`"* - Or did I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

As several people have pointed out previously, you redirect to another file. At that point, all locally defined variables are gone - you no longer have access to them.

Look into PHP sessions [in PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Sessions will allow you to transfer these variables from request to request. However, sessions will only work if you are running some form of webserver.

UPDATE: Also to note, as other people (once again) have pointed out, $selected_button = "Option One" will ONLY apply inside the "scope" of the function detailBuilder. So calling detailBuilder() creates a variable called $selected_button inside the function, and then immediately discards it.

UPDATE 2.0: Sorry for so many updates. Here's an example of setting a session:

Update 3.0: updated code slightly

First things first. Make sure you start the session.

```
session_start();
```

You're going to have to call `session_start()` at the start of any php script! That means that the first file that executes every time should have session_start() at the top.

External Script:

```
$_SESSION["selected_option"] = "Option One";
```

Script where originally it was undefined:

```
$selected_details  = $_SESSION["selected_option"];
?>
<h4><?=$selected_details?></h4>
```

Comment: you may want to update to include `session_start()` - this may indeed be his first rodeo.

Comment: I was wondering how far down that rabbit hole I should go, but I can at least include that. Good idea, thanks.